# Select first class which after a specific class

Tags: html, css

In the following markup, I want to apply css to only div with class `.box` which comes **immediately after the .wrap**. If it comes after the `<p>` or any other class than the `.wrap`, I do not want to select it.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">Apply style to this box</div>
    <p>random</p>
    <div class="box">Do not apply style to this box</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to look the adjacent sibling selector, but does not seem to work in this case.

```
.wrap + .box{
    background: red;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8fjuz7sm/

I cannot use `:first-child` as it can occur only once too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

```
.wrap .box:first-of-type{
    background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/8fjuz7sm/2/).

OR

```
.wrap .box:nth-of-type(1){
    background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/8fjuz7sm/3/).

Answer (score 0):

as @Hiral says, you'll have to either use `first-of-type` or `nth-of-type(1)`.

If you cannot do this, but have access to the html, you'll have to add another class to the elements you wish to apply the class on, such as

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box red">Apply style to this box</div>
<p>random</p>
<div class="box">Do not apply style to this box</div>
</div>
```

or you can use javascript and/or jquery to select the first element then apply styling via javascript.

- Jquery Example

`$(".wrap .box").eq(0).css("Background-color","red")`

Answer (score 0):

I edited your JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/8fjuz7sm/4/

I recommend using jQuery for this because older browsers may not support the pure css solution :

create a new class :

```
.wrapperbox {
    background: red;
}
```

Then add this jQuery code to your script :

```
$( ".wrap > .box:first" ).addClass( "wrapperbox" );
```

After this every html element with the class wrap which has a child box will get a class wrapperbox and there you can do your css

When you dont want to do jQuery you can use this :

```
.wrap .box:first-of-type{
    background:red;
}
```

It will select the first child of wrap with the class name box and then do your css